# What exactly domainprep does?

Tags: active-directory, domain

Primarily `forestprep` does schema update. Similarly search for 'domainprep' but not able to find appropriate answer for why it is used?

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a clue in the names. Forestprep prepares the forest schema, and domainprep prepares the domain schema. You would need to run both to upgrade DCs, install Exchange, etc.